# How to make a Number/Letter interval in Python

Tags: python, matrix, intervals

So ...
Am writing a code that makes a Matrix table then **calculate how many** ( uppercase Letter , Lowercase Letter , Numbers , Symbols )

That's the code i tried :

```
def Proc_Affiche(T,P,X):
    Nb_Maj = 0
    Nb_Min = 0
    Nb_chiffre = 0
    Nb_symbole = 0
    for i in range(P):
        for j in range(X):
            if T[i] in ["A","Z"]:
                Nb_Maj = Nb_Maj + 1
            elif T[i] in ["a","z"] :
                Nb_Min = Nb_Min + 1
            elif T[i] in range(1,9):
                Nb_chiffre = Nb_chiffre + 1
            else :
                Nb_symbole = Nb_symbole + 1
    print("Nb_Maj= ",Nb_Maj)
    print("Nb_Min= ",Nb_Min)
    print("Nb_chiffre= ",Nb_chiffre)
    print("Nb_symbole= ",Nb_symbole)
```

So the Output should be like that :

```
Nb_Maj=  ...
Nb_Min=  ...
Nb_chiffre=  ...
Nb_symbole=  ...
```

The Problem is on the part of intervals Like `["A","Z"]`

Comment: Please provide an example on how T is created, you say it's a matrix yet you treat it as an array (list).
It will also help to explain what each one of X and P stand for.

Comment: Your code seems ok. What problem do you have? C'est quoi ton problème ? ;-)

Comment: For exemple T = [ a , b, r, 4 , $ , 7 ] . Nb_Maj = 0 , Nb_min = 3 . Nb_num = 2 , Nb_Symb = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings have some functions you can use to check what they contain

- `.isalpha()` is true for letters
- `.isnumeric()` is true for numbers
- `.isalnum()` is true for letters and numbers
- `.isupper()` is true for uppercase

Thus you could do something like

```py
if T[i].isalpha():
    if T[i].isupper():
        Nb_Maj += 1
    else:
        Nb_Min += 1
elif T[i].isnumeric():
    Nb_chiffre += 1
else:
    Nb_symbole += 1
```

Comment: Gave me this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

Comment: try replace `T[i]` with `T[i][j]`, looks like you have a list of lists

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want 100%, but I think something like follows would fit:

```
def Proc_Affiche(T,P,X):
   Nb_Maj = 0
   Nb_Min = 0
   Nb_chiffre = 0
   Nb_symbole = 0
   for i in range(P):
      for j in range(X):
        if "A" <= T[i][j] <= "Z":
            Nb_Maj = Nb_Maj + 1
        elif "a" <= T[i][j] <= "z" :
            Nb_Min = Nb_Min + 1
        elif 1 <= T[i][j] <= 9:
            Nb_chiffre = Nb_chiffre + 1
        else :
            Nb_symbole = Nb_symbole + 1
   print("Nb_Maj= ",Nb_Maj)
   print("Nb_Min= ",Nb_Min)
   print("Nb_chiffre= ",Nb_chiffre)
   print("Nb_symbole= ",Nb_symbole)
```

Comment: It gave me an error : ``` if "A" <= T[i] <= "Z":
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list' ```

Comment: You trying to compare a whole row?

Comment: If the table is 3 X 3 , so i have to check all the 9 cases

Comment: @koukou in this case you have to go through all the elements using T[i][j], I edited my code, try it now

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is , here is the whlole code if that would help :

```
from math import*

def Proc_saisie():
    X = -1
    while X < 1 or X > 20 :
        X = int(input("Donner un entier entre 5 et 20 : "))
    return X


def Proc_Remplir(P,X):
    T= [[] for i in range(P)]
    for i in range(P):
        for j in range(X):
            d = input("T["+str(i)+","+str(j)+"]=")
            T[i].append(d)
    return T

def Proc_Affiche(T,P,X):
    Nb_Maj = 0
    Nb_Min = 0
    Nb_chiffre = 0
    Nb_symbole = 0
    for i in range(P):
        for j in range(X):
            if T[i] in ["A","Z"]:
                Nb_Maj = Nb_Maj + 1
            elif T[i] in ["a","z"] :
                Nb_Min = Nb_Min + 1
            elif T[i] in range(1,9):
                Nb_chiffre = Nb_chiffre + 1
            else :
                Nb_symbole = Nb_symbole + 1
    print("Nb_Maj= ",Nb_Maj)
    print("Nb_Min= ",Nb_Min)
    print("Nb_chiffre= ",Nb_chiffre)
    print("Nb_symbole= ",Nb_symbole)


#---------------------------

L = Proc_saisie()

C = Proc_saisie()
print("L =",L)
print("C =",C)
TAB = []

TAB = Proc_Remplir(L,C)


TAB = Proc_Affiche(TAB,L,C)
```